# ios - simulator looks different from the layout on the storyboard screen

Tags: ios, ios5, storyboard

I am having a strange situation. I created a very simple screen with some buttons on the storyboard, then when I ran the emulator (is it correct to say simulator or emulator?) it got the spacing wrong for one of the buttons.

I am adding a screenshot. The emulator is to the right of the storyboard screen.

Any idea why this may happen?

[image]

I thought it was a problem with the button. And it might have been. But when I took out two lower buttons, I got something even weirder as shown on this screenshot:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure all your buttons have the same parent view and layout commands. It may be that the button is working off of a different parent frame than the rest of them.

Comment: @Bergasms could you please clarify what you mean by parent view? I really only have these screens in the app so far.

Comment: it's ok, other people have better responses. What i mean was, sometimes in a complicated view you have a lot of subviews. Occasionally when you are moving things around interface builder will put the thing into a different parent view based on what it thinks you are doing. Then this can have some unintended results because the new parent view has a different coordinate frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are using Autolayout, and all your buttons except Investment has a Top constraint while Investment has a Bottom constraint, causing Investment's distance to bottom to stay the same when the screen grows taller.

Click on Investment button, click [Editor -> Pin -> Top space to Superview] in the top menu.

Click Investment button again. Click the second tab from the right in the right panel (the one where you can set frame). Look for a Top Space to Superview constraint, right click and delete. If there isn't one, then XCode did its job. Try running simulator again.

Edit: I just want to say that XCode has a habit of adding Top constraints for you when the view you just dragged into the xib is in the upper half of its container, and Bottom constraints when it's in the bottom half. I know XCode is trying to help but it drives me crazy sometimes.

Comment: Editor section also helped me Click on Editor -> Resolve Auto layout issues -> Reset to suggested constraints

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're using a 3.5" simulator and laying out for a 4" device, so the view will be resized.

If you're using autoresize masks, are some of the autoresize masks on your buttons incorrect? You probably want them all to stick to the top of the screen. Check to make sure the autosizing for each of your buttons matches this image. (You'll need to click the "ruler" icon to see these settings.)

[image: autoresize pic]

Comment: hmmm, not sure what is happening but I just tried to take out the button that was causing the problems, and it made the emulator wider for some reason. Also...to get to the screen which you showed, shat should I select in the storyboard?  Thank you!

Comment: You should select each button and check the settings for it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you're using the XCode4 which provides NSAutoLayout as default. When you place an object to the storyboard NSAutolayout automatically creates constrains which layouts the object on the screen automatically for different devices(iPhone4,iPhone5) or orientations(portrait/landscape). Please check NSAutolayout class and constrains. if you want you can remove the NSAutolayout and your objects will be displayed on the simulator normal but in that case you have to manually adjust your objects for different orientations and screens

Hope helps.